# How to call pages by Ajax using javascript

Tags: 7, ajax

I've a created an Ajax-callback page using my module available as `myModule/somepage/%/%` - you can see that last two arguments in this page changes dynamically.

I want to make an AJAX call to this page, writing javascript. Say, when I click a button an ajax call will be made to this page (POST method preferably for the two arguments).

I know how to create hyper-links that handle Ajax calls automatically, but in that way links are static, and I can not send arguments to my Ajax-callback page. So how do I write JavaScript to make an Ajax call to my page?

Comment: Here is an example that uses jquery library: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

Comment: I'd like to know who is the down-voter and kind explanation what I did wrong here!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to make POST req to a webpage.

```
$('#yourid').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theUrl = base_url + 'myModule/somepage';
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: "name=John&location=Boston"
        success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        $('#displydiv').html(msg);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it going to work with Drupal's Ajax framework?

Comment: It works, but it returns a complete Drupal page with all it's HTMLs, css, everything... what I need to output is simple JSON data or something like that. :(

Comment: Try print and exit the html not return.

Comment: Would that be a Drupal-way, to exit after printing?

Comment: Its just a security belt.

Answer (score 0):

> Say, when I click a **button** an ajax call will be made to this page

If you want a form which has AJAX then you need to look at the [FormAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). [This article](http://drupal.org/node/752056) also explain in quite good detail on how to build AJAX forms. If you want something other than forms then I suggest looking at jQuery API for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There's also a shorthand for jQuery.ajax which is [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: I saw the FAPI's #ajax property, but in my special case I'm not getting it done. The form is hidden and Drupal is not submitting it at all, which I specified in this question: . I need some other way to submit the form, that's why I'm asking the Ajax way.

Answer (score 0):

There is good documentation about FAPI and AJAX:

- [AJAX forms in D7](http://drupal.org/node/752056)
- [Examples for Defelopers module](http://drupal.org/node/752056)